# Difference between npm run watch and npm run watch-poll

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-mix

What is the difference between `npm run watch` and `npm run watch-poll` in Laravel mix?

I cannot see any difference between the output they give.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Comment: Future readers should note that this is a question about [Laravel Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) , which is a wrapper around Webpack that can be used with or without Laravel.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`watch` will listen for file changes, however, on certain systems this won't always work.

`watch-poll` periodically checks (polls) for changes e.g. every 1000ms it will manually check to see if any files have changed.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/

Comment: at least for me watch-poll also have a weird downside: memory leak of sorts...

Answer (score 17):

`watch-poll` is an alternative to `watch` in certain enviroments `watch` might not track changes properly, therefore `watch-poll` was implemented.

Poll will check the files every x seconds rather than automatically picking up on changes through watching.

You can read up on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix#running-mix) for a more information about mix.